# SED program works but when trying to execute as script it doesn't

Tags: sed

My `sed` command works when I enter it followed by the file name but when I saved it in a file and used `chmod u+rx` to give it executable permission it doesn't work. The command is `sed 's/\.\s*$/.\n/'` .

Here is what happens

```
tim@tim-desktop:~$ ./dlsp lines
THIS IS Just A BLANK LINE.
```

If I enter it with followed by a file name it does what it is suppose to do

```
tim@tim-desktop:~$ sed 's/\.\s*$/.\n/' lines
Line one.

The second line.

The third.

This is line four.

five.

This is the sixth sentence.

This is line seven.

Eighth and last.
```

Comment: Post the `dlsp` script.

Comment: Re-double-spaced the output since that's what the `sed` command is trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that your `dlsp` script is passing the filename argument on to `sed`:

```
sed 's/\.\s*$/.\n/' $1
#                   ^^ This is the important bit!
```

If you don't do that, it will seem to sit there forever as it's waiting for you to type in an input file since, without an argument, it reads from standard input.

Comment: I was missing the $1 I didn't even think about the input that's kinda important. Thanks for the help

Comment: @user2177712 It's important to mark answer accepted for it to be considered as solved. I keep jumping into your questions, most of which are already solved but do not indicate so.